# How to allow privileges for a user to create random-named database in Cpanel (Silverstripe)

Tags: database, automated-tests, cpanel, silverstripe, whm

I'm trying to setup [automated testing on Silverstripe](http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/topics/testing/)! in CPanel. When I ran any of the test in url (for my case it is DOMAIN/dev/tests/AggregateTest), it says

> Fatal error: Couldn't run query: CREATE DATABASE `tmpdb2605857` Access denied for user 
>   'todaytes_root'@'localhost' to database 'tmpdb2605857' in 
>   /home/todaytes/public_html/sapphire/core/model/MySQLDatabase.php on line 525

Silverstripe will create a random-named database every time the test executed and destroy it after the test finished.

From the "databases" menu in cPanel, I am only allowed to add database and user manually with some prefix name for it (in my case, all my database and user start with todaytes_). How do I configure cPanel/WHM to give permission to the user so that Silverstripe Automated Test could work fine?

Answer (score 0):

cPanel user doesn't have access to create database with random names. The databases created from cPanel always have prefix "username_"

If you have root access to the server then you can use MySQL root username and password to do this. You can get the MySQL root username and password from the file /root/.my.cnf

Comment: Hi, I do have root access to the server. How do I go ahead and use MySQL root username and password to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- You can define `SS_DATABASE_PREFIX` in your `_ss_environment.php` file, setting it to "username_".  This will affect the name of the temp db used.
- If you don't want to use a random database name, you could modify `SapphireTest::create_temp_db()`.